# Going for Unsung Hero-- Is there an easy way of checking my answer count, against the criteria for the badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I think I'm near the Unsung Hero badge, but I'm not sure.  I, like many, am rather busy-- is there a way I can quickly check my count instead of having to look at each answer with 0 votes?  I've answer quite a few of my own questions. :/  Beginning to wish I had rather deleted the questions I answered myself, so that this would be easier to discern.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521 or http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45192/how-many-more-accepted-answers-do-i-need-until-tenacious-unsung-hero

Comment: So you don't want any more upvotes? I'll try to remember that.

Comment: Well, yes, I do.  I just felt I was getting pretty close to getting (what would be) my first gold badge.  I'm not on this site for the badges... but I can't say I don't mind earning them. ;)  I'll take all the upvotes I can get on answers that have already been upvoted.